# Is C++ destructor called after java exception is thrown from JNI function?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I wonder if `~JniFloatArray` of `dataArray` is called, when `com/emcjpn/sleep/SleepAlgorithmBreakException` is thrown?

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL    Java_com_emcjpn_sleep_SleepAlgorithm_nativePushNewDataAndCalculate(JNIEnv *env, jclass type,
                                                                       jlong ptr, jfloatArray data_) {
        JniFloatArray dataArray(data_, env);
        jfloat *data = dataArray.getData();

        SleepAlgorithm* algorithm = (SleepAlgorithm*)ptr;
        jsize length = dataArray.length();
        SleepAlgorithmResult result = algorithm->pushNewDataAndCalculate(data, data + length);
        if (result.shouldBreak) {
            jclass exception = env->FindClass("com/emcjpn/sleep/SleepAlgorithmBreakException");
            env->ThrowNew(exception, "sleep calculation failed, invalid ecg data");
            return NULL;
        }

        /*Some other code*/
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint in the destructor?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It's hard to find in the JNI documentation, but `env->ThrowNew` doesn't actually throw an exception immediately.  Instead it sets things up so that an exception is thrown once you return to Java-land.

This means you *must* follow `ThrowNew` with a return of some sort (to get back to Java-land), and that return will cause all the destructors to run.

Comment: In the posted code, it's also probably a good idea to check if the call to `FindClass()` succeeded before trying to throw a NULL exception object.